# repeat function n times in recursion on input (without loop recur)

Tags: clojure

I know I can solve my problem with loop and recur but it seems such a simple (common?) operation that I was wondering if there was no single function in clojure or less cluttered approach then loop/ recur to solve this. I searched for it but was not able to find something.

The function I was looking for is the following.

```
(the-function n input some-function)
```

where n is the number of time to recursivle call some-function on the input.

A simple example would be:

```
(the-function 3 1 (fn [x] (+ x 1)))
=> 4
```

Is ther anything like that in Clojure?

Best regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is basically `iterate`. It will generate an infinite sequence of repeated applications of a function to a seed input. So to replicate the behavior you describe here, you would write:

```
(nth (iterate some-function input) n)
```

Comment: Wonderfull, exactly what I was look for. It was in plain sight the whole time and I still overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(defn your-iterate-fn [times init-param the-fn] 
    (last (take (inc times) (iterate the-fn init-param))))
(your-iterate-fn 3 1 (fn [x] (+ x 1)))
==> 4
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works but the solution with nth above is a bit more elegant. :)